# Probability that balls are picked randomly from a bag

Tags: probability

I have a bag with 50 balls. 15 are red and 35 are green. Somebody picks (without replacement) 10 balls and they are all green. I have 2 related but different questions:

1. What is the probability that this happened if the person picking the balls did so randomly.
2. What is the probability that the person who picked the balls did, indeed, pick them randomly.

The answer to 1) should be straightforward and if I’m not mistaken, is:

$$p = \prod_{i=1}^{10} \frac{35-i+1}{50-i+1} = 1.79 \%$$

However, I’m not sure of how to go about 2).

Comment: The first should be $\binom {35}{10}\big / \binom {50}{10}$ which is not what you wrote.  The second cannot be answered without an a priori distribution on the selection methods or something like that.

Comment: Note, there's nothing wrong with the formula you wrote, so I expect you just have a computational error.  I get $0.017871342$ for the probability.

Comment: @lulu, you are right, there was an error in my calculation which I've now fixed. However I'm still scratching my head for the second question.

Comment: As I say, the second question can not be answered as it stands. It is perfectly possible to have obtained this outcome from a perfectly random draw.  We need more information, or more assumptions to say anything further and there aren't any quick guess assumptions I can think of.